# Separating Get request Response body in java Socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, get, httpresponse, bufferedreader

I'm trying to write a curl like program using java, which uses only java socket programming (and not apache http client or any other APIs)
I want to have the option of showing whole or only the body of the response to my get request to user. Currently came up with the following code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String t;
        while ((t = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (t.isEmpty() && !parameters.isVerbose()) {
                StringBuilder responseData = new StringBuilder();
                while ((t = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseData.append(t).append("\r\n");
                }
                System.out.println(responseData.toString());
                parameters.verbose = false;
                break;
            } else if(parameters.isVerbose())// handle output
                System.out.println(t);
        }
        br.close();
```

When the verbose option is on, it works quick and shows the whole response body in less than a second. but when I want to just have the body of the message it takes too much time(approx 10 sec) to hand it out.
Does any one knows how can it be processed in a faster way?
Thank you.

Comment: Just a comment: the structure of the code is pretty weird because you consume the entire stream in the inner loop, therefore the outer loop is useless in the non-verbose case. You could also fix your variable names (`s` and `t` aren't explicit names).

Comment: Could it be that the verbose switch is active at another place in your code? It seems that you send a header like `Connection: close` in aone case but not in the other.

Comment: @blafasel I tried it with the exactly same data and just a boolean difference. when I'm printing the whole thing, it work perfectly and fast. But when processing on having only the data it become quite slow!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume what you mean by slow is that it starts displaying something almost immediately but keeps on printing lines for a long time. Writing to the console takes time, and you're printing each line invidually while in the other code path you first store the entire response in memory and then flush it to the console.

If the verbose response is small enough to fit in memory, you should do the same, otherwise you can decide on an arbitrary number of lines to print in batches (i.e; you accumulate `n` lines in memory and then flush to the console, clear the `StringBuilder`and repeat).

The most elegant way to implement my suggestion is to use a `PrintStream` wrapping a `BufferedOutputStream`, itself wrapping `System.out`. All my comments and advices are condensed in the following snippet:

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

public static void printResponse(Socket socket, Parameters parameters) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
         PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out, BUFFER_SIZE))) {

        // there is no functional difference in your code between the verbose and non-verbose code paths
        // (they have the same output). That's a bug, but I'm not fixing it in my snippet as I don't know
        // what you intended to do.
        br.lines().forEach(line -> printStream.append(line).append("\r\n"));
    }
}
```

If it uses any language construct you don't know about, feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, nothing start displaying for seconds and then all come together!
And the outputs of verbose and non-verbose are different. one shows the whole response and the other just the data received in the response.

Comment: So the way of getting the body is that body is separated with a blank line from the rest of response. that part is for taking out the body.

Comment: @Fezo I don't see any difference in your code. You display all the lines in both cases (except for the first one in the non-verbose case but only if it's empty so no much difference).

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ?